# Alter text in span tag dynamically with React issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React code I have the following code in a span element.

```
<span>
 slutdatum: {item.end}
  &nbsp;-&nbsp;{week}&nbsp;veckor
</span>
```

I would like to change the text in my span element "veckor" if the value of {week} is larger then 1, else the text should be "vecka"

Could this be done with some sort of ternary condition? I am quite new to JavaScript and React.

Answer (score 2):

You can render it conditionally like follows

```
<span>
 slutdatum: {item.end}
  &nbsp;-&nbsp;{week}&nbsp;{week > 1 ? 'veckor' : 'vecka' }
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was tinkering around with something similar, thanks again :)